# Remove nil value from array of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

My array of hash is like:

```
[
  {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"},
  {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"}, 
  {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, 
  {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}, 
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, 
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil},
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil},
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, 
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, 
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, 
  {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}
]
```

How can I remove `nil` values if in my hash `id` is `nil`?

Comment: Please edit to clarify (even though you've selected an answer, as many people may read your question in future). "How can I remove `nil` value if my hash `id` is `nil`? doesn't make sense. You can remove values without removing keys.  Perhaps you mean you want to remove all hashes `h` for which `h[:id].nil? #=> true`? If so, say so (and if your array is `a`, do you want to modify `a` or return an array equal to `a` with some (hash) elements removed?), Be precise in all things Ruby!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
arr.reject{|h| h[:id].nil?}

=> [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"},
    {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"},
    {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"},
    {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}]
```

[**Demo**](http://repl.it/xnW/3)

Or `select`:

```
arr.select { |h| h[:id] }
```

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/xnW/4)

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is to **remove** element which hash `id` is `nil` then better to use **[delete_if](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)**

```
array.delete_if { |h| h[:id].nil? }
 => [
      {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, 
      {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"},
      {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, 
      {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}
    ]
```

**Note:** [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) will returns a **new array** containing the items in `self` for which the given block is not `true`. While [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) will Deletes every element of `self` for which block evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get all hashes whose values are not all `nil`. You can do that by:

```
arr = [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}, {:id=>nil, :name=>nil, :type=>nil}]

arr.find_all { |h| !h.values.compact.empty? }
# => [{:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!107", :name=>"Folder 11", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!105", :name=>"Pictures", :type=>"album"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!113", :name=>"Public", :type=>"folder"}, {:id=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!124", :name=>"sasd", :type=>"folder"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [select method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to filter the array.

```
list = list.select { |item| item[:id] != nil }
```